Jupyter Lab Desktop- how to increase memory limit?
I am trying to run a code in Jupyter lab desktop, but the kernel keeps dying halfway through.  I am quite sure that it is due to the application running out of memory since this has happened to me before.  I remember a long time ago I was able to increase the memory limit somewhere (I think I was using Jupyter notebook) in a config file with a parameter called "MEM_LIMIT" or something similar.  However, I can't seem to find how to do this again, or how to do it in Jupyter lab.  Does anyone have any insight on where to find this config file or what it might be called?  Any insight is much appreciated, thanks.
